# Check if component is in View

Tags: react-native

I have components like below

```xml
<Animated.ScrollView
    onScroll = {Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
        { useNativeDriver: true, listener: (event) => handleScroll(event) }
    )}

    scrollEventThrottle = {16}
    alwaysBounceHorizontal = {false}
    alwaysBounceVertical = {false}
    bounces = {false}>

        <View style = {{height:100}}><Text>One</Text></View>

        <View style = {{height:100}}><Text>Two</Text></View>

        <View style = {{height:100}}><Text>Three</Text></View>

<Animated.ScrollView>
```

I am able to get get Scroll Y position using

```js
const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);
```

Now how do I get the positions of view so I can get that values to compute and add animations to it.

For example, when I scroll down and if `View - Three` becomes completely visible inside the viewport, I need to change some styles to it. And remove the styles if its going away from the viewport... How do I do it?

Comment: Why an Animated Scrollview ?

Comment: The number of views in your scrollview is always the same ?

Comment: I am going to animate based on my scroll position.. And no number of views changes based on my API response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a good way.

Because your list is variable, use FlatList to render your elements, and use onViewableItemsChanged to detect wich have changed.

In this example i animate the opacity of views

Init

```
// fetch api => response
let animatedValues = []
response.forEach(element => {
    animatedValues.push(new Animated.Value(0))
})
```

Handle

```
const handleViewsChange = (event) => {
    let animations = []
    event.changed.forEach(view => {
        animations.push(
            Animated.timing(animatedValues[view.index], {
                toValue: view.isViewable ? 1 : 0,
                duration: 300,
                useNativeDriver: true
            })
        )
    })
    Animated.parallel(animations).start()
}
```

Your list

```
<Flatlist
    data={response}
    renderItem={(item, index) => {
        return(
            <Animated.View key={index} style={{height:100, opacity: animatedValues[index]}}><Text>{item.thing}</Text></Animated.View>
        )
    }}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    onViewableItemsChanged={event => handleViewsChange(event)}
/>
```

You will surely have to adapt for your use